# Как к Unity подключить Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio

Когда устанавливал Unity, была установлена версия VS 2017, но в данный момент я бы хотел перейти на VS 2019, но в Preferences Unity нет версии VS 2019, хотя она есть на моем компьютере. Как поменять версию VS с 2017 на 2019 в Unity?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вручную найти исполняемый файл VS2019. Там же есть у вас пункт `Browse... `

Answer (score 0):

***1 способ*** - Попробуй вот что. Открой скрипт в папке проекта, который ты хочешь отредактировать. Потом дважды на него нажми. Появится вот такое диалоговое окно, а там по пункту Выбрать из установленных выбери тот редактор, который ты хочешь использовать. Теперь Unity всегда будет открывать твой скрипт через выбранный тобою редактор.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***2 способ*** - Вернитесь обратно в это окошко из вашего скриншота, нажмите там на пункт Browse и просто найдите ярлычок вашего желаемого редактора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]